# Add prefix to multiple column names: SAS

Tags: sas

I am trying to rename columns in a dataframe:

```
data work.baseline;
    set work.ehp30 (keep = Pat_TNO AssNo pain -- family sexual -- infertile);
    where AssNo = 1;
run;
```

Which returns a dataframe to `work.baseline` with columns `Pat_TNO`, `AssNo`, and 11 columns between `pain` and `infertile`. I would like to rename the 11 columns to `baseline_pain`, `baseline_infertile`, etc, without affecting `Pat_TNO` and `AssNo`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if you can use this as an example. Here, I rename all variables except Name and Sex to be prefixed by 'baseline_'.

```
data class;
   set sashelp.class;
run;

data test;
   set sashelp.vcolumn end = z;
   where libname='WORK' and memname='CLASS' and name not in ('Name', 'Sex');
 
   if _n_ = 1 then 
      call execute('proc datasets lib=work nolist; modify class;');

      call execute(compbl(cat('rename ', name, '= baseline_', name, ';')));

   if z then call execute('quit;');

run;

proc contents data = class;
run;
```

Comment: Some modifying but got there, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate way that does not involve a dictionary table.

```
data have; 
  retain A B C D E F G H I J K L 0;
  stop;
run;

data _null_;
  dsid = open ('work.have(keep=c--g)');
  if dsid;

  call execute ('proc datasets nolist lib=work;modify have;rename');

  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (sysmsg()=:'ERROR');
    name = varname(dsid,_n_);
    if not missing(name) then 
      call execute (catx('=',name,'baseline_'||name));
  end;

  call execute (';quit;');
run;
```